# How to skip header part of BMP image

Tags: java, bitmap, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I need to process the body part of a bitmap image and for that I need to skip the header part of bitmap image.

How can I identify the number of bytes occupied by the header of the bitmap image? This is what I'm doing now but there has to be a better way:

```
class Test{

        public static void main(String ... a){          

        try{
               //I can't find any ideas to skip the header portion of bmp image
                FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:\\ja\\text1.bmp");


            BufferedImage bi=ImageIO.read(fis);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bi,"bmp",baos);

            baos.flush();

            byte [] data=baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();

            double i=0;

                System.out.print(data.length);  
            while(i<data.length){

                //data[(int)i]=(byte)0xFF;
                if(i>5000d && i<17000d)
                data[(int)i]=0;

                i++;                                    
            }
            //edit it.....

            ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

            bi=ImageIO.read(bais);

            ImageIO.write(bi,"bmp",new File("C:\\ja\\text2.bmp"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){         
        e.printStackTrace();

        }           

        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should first get the `bfOffBits` field of the File Header: http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/getteched/bmp/bmpfileformat.htm

Comment: What processing are you trying to do, and why do you need to skip the header for that? Note that you can't use `ImageIO.read(...)` to read the image after you skipped the header, as the header contains the the bytes needed to determine image format, dimensions and other important aspects of the image.

Comment: @HaraldK a valid case for needing to skip the header data of a bmp is if it is being embedded in a Windows .ico or .cur format file.  In this case, the header data is written elsewhere in the file, so the spec requires that the BITMAPFILEHEADER be excluded from the image data block itself.